# Change anchor text and icon using jquery bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html code:

```
<a class="btn pull-left" id="btnSelectAll"><i class="icon-plus"></i>
   Select All
</a>
```

When I click the button I need to toggle the text to "Deselect All" and also change the class of the `<i>` to "icon-minus", for each click should change between one or the other. I tried with toggle on the anchor but didn't work. I don't want to hardcode the text because it can be in a different language.

Here is what I tried:

```
$("#btnSelectAll").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('show');

    if ($this.hasClass('show')) {
        $this.text('@L.GetLanguageText("DeselectAll")');
        $($this +'> i').addClass('icon-minus');
    } else {
        $this.text('@L.GetLanguageText("SelectAll")');
        $($this + '> i').addClass('icon-plus');
    }
});
```

but it doesn't change the icon.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just missing a few css adjustments, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zs5Ew/2/).

js:

```
var alterIcon = function()
{
    $("#btnSelectAll").click(function() {
        var icon = $(this).children("i"),
            text = $(this).text();

        $(this).text(text == "Deselect All" ? "Select All" : "Deselect All");
        $(this).prepend(icon.toggleClass('glyphicon-thumbs-up glyphicon-thumbs-down') );
    });
}
alterIcon();
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YDqZW/

html:

```
<a class="btn pull-left" id="btnSelectAll"><i class="icon-plus"></i>
   Select All
</a>
```

js:

```
$('#btnSelectAll').on('click', function() {
     var notice = 'Select All';

     if ( $('#btnSelectAll').text().trim() == notice ) {
          notice = 'Deselect All';
     }

     $('#btnSelectAll').find('i').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus').parent().contents().last()[0].textContent = notice;  
});
```

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the text because it can be in a different language

Comment: The text is coming from database translated

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for size:

```
$("#btnSelectAll").on("click", function() {
    x = $(this).children()[0];
    $(this).text().trim() == "Select All" ? $(this).text("Deselect All").prepend(x) : $(this).text("Select All").prepend(x);
    $($(this).children()[0]).toggleClass("icon-plus icon-minus");
});
```